# ngPicky colour picker issue

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I am trying to use [ngPicky colour picker](https://github.com/danprince/ng-picky). I am not sure how to define the directive or avoid the error I get while using with a php script.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'color' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in .../themes/Silk_af_v155/index.template.php on line 834

```
825: }
826: 
827: function template_colour_picker()
828: 
829: {
830: echo'
831:     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ngPicky" ng-model="color">
832:     <input type="picker" ng-model="color">
833:      <div class="category_header forum_category" style="background:{{color | toHex}};"></div>

834:   <picker color='color'></picker>';

835: }
836: 
837: template_colour_picker();
```

After following suggestion given in the first answer

http://adminforum.in/index.php?thread/1079-colour-picker-for-elkarte/&postID=5438#post5438

**Edit --**

Inspect element

```
<title>Admin Forum - Index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/elktest/themes/Silk_af_v155/css/index.css" id="index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/elktest/themes/Silk_af_v155/css//ng-picky.css" id="ng-picky.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/elktest/themes/Silk_af_v155/css//af.css" id="af.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/elktest/themes/default/css/font-awesome.min.css" id="font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/elktest/themes/Silk_af_v155/css/_silk/index_silk.css" id="index_silk.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/elktest/themes/default/css/portal.css" id="portal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/elktest/themes/Silk_af_v155/css/_silk/custom_silk.css" id="custom_silk.css">
<div class="category_header forum_category" style="background:{{color | toHex}};"></div><style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried using `<picker color="color"></picker>`?

Comment: Thanks, it removed the error. But there is no sign of picker on the page. :(

Comment: When debugging, does the <picker>-element appear in the generated code? Maybe the picker-directive is not included correctly?

Comment: This is the inspect element

Comment: I guess ngPicky.css is loading only after picker is loaded. How to make sure that HTML code placed on the last line of a php file come last, not first ?